# Linear systems for matrices

Tags: matrices

Component X costs 5, Component Y costs 10, and Component Z costs 15 dollars respectively. 1200 components were sold amassing 10000 dollars. Component Y sold the sum of Components X and Z sold.

Ok, so I need to form 3 equations for the linear system. I could see

$ x + y + z = 1200$

$ 5x + 10y + 15z = 10000$

$ x + z = y$

I don't think that is correct, but I can't see any more detail in the question to provide an alternative.

Comment: Looks good to me. Do you need to write this as a matrix equation?

Comment: It looks OK. If you want to use the matrix form, rewrite the last equation as $x-y+z=0$

Comment: Yes I need to turn it into a matrix. So, x - y + z = 0 would be written as 1, -1, 1, 0 in matrix form?

Answer (score 1):

Your system is correct and according to my solution the answers are $$ (x,y,z)= (500, 600, 100)$$

You may solved the system by elimination method